# Uploading images into a specific folder php

Tags: php, html

So I'm doing an online store for a project and I need help doing one thing:
after I add a product in the admin panel, I have to manualy pick the image and paste on the specific folder; I would like to know how could I insert the image to 3 specific folders.

I should have something like:

```
if else {
    Cat_type ---> Drones
    the image go too res/got
}
if else {
    Cat_type ---> Computers
    the image go too res/hp
}
Else {
    Cat_type ---> Laptops
    the image go too res/hg
}
```

So, for example, in the database when I choose the image, I get the name of the image after that, I need to copy and past the image to the folders I showed you. What do I need to do to upload the images automaticly to the folders?

[image]

**This is where i add products**
[image: This is where i add products]

**add_product.php:**

```
        <?php
    session_start();
    include_once("config.php");

    //current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL
    $current_url = urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Add Product | Fly With US</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="res/flywithus-pt.png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/head.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sidebar2.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/content.css">
    <!--BOOTSTRAP-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            margin: 0;                      
        }
        #logo{
            padding-top: 0.7%;                      
            width: 14%;
            height: 62px;
            float: left;    
            position: fixed;        
        }
        #addForm{
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 30px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="logo">
    <a href="admin.php">
        <img src="res/flywithus-png.png" width="50%">
    </a>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></li>

        <li>
            <a href="destroy.php"> 
            <table><tr><td><img src="res/icons/logout2.png" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;Logout</td></tr></table></a>
        </li>

        <li>&nbsp;</li>

    </ul>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="inventory.php">Inventory</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="add_product.php">Add Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="remove_product.php">Remove Product</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- BACK TO TOP-->
<a href="#" class="back-to-top">Back To Top </a>

<!--CONTENT-->

<div class="content" style="color: white;">
    <section class="container">

<!-- FORM -->
<div id="addForm">
<form name="productForm" method="post" action="add.php">
<table width="45%"> 
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Product Code &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>    
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" name="product_code" required>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <label>cat_type &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>    
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
    <input type="text" name="cat_type" required>     
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Category &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>    
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" name="category" required>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Product Name &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>    
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" name="product_name" required>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Price &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>   
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" name="price" required>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Quantity &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>    
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" name="product_qty" required>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Photo &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>   
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="file" name="product_img_name" required>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
    <input type="submit" name="addproduct" value="Add Product" class="click">
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</div>


</section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**add.php:**

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");


        $code = ($_POST['product_code']);
        $name = ($_POST['product_name']);
        $cat = ($_POST['category']);
        $cat_type = ($_POST['cat_type']);
        $fees = ($_POST['price']);
        $quant = ($_POST['product_qty']);
        $photo = ($_POST['product_img_name']);



$sql = "INSERT INTO products(product_code,product_name,category,cat_type,price,product_qty,product_img_name) VALUES ('$code','$name','$cat','$cat_type','$fees','$quant', '$photo')";

if (mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("New product added. Add more!");</script>';
    header("Location:http://localhost/Fly With US/add_product.php");
} 
else 
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error Occured");</script>';
    header("Location:http://localhost/Fly With US/add_product.php");
}



?>
```

Comment: Can you post the part where you deal with the uploaded file? Or don't you have any of that yet?

Comment: don't have dat yet because i don't know where i should insert the code , probably on the button?

Comment: I've done *some* editing to properly format your code. It would go down well here if you were to finish the job off!

Comment: @Adrian can u share ?

Comment: @DarkBee where?

Comment: `<form name="productForm" method="post" action="add.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >`

Comment: @DarkBee yeah but need to enter more code, if u can share in answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave here an example on how to upload a photo to a folder:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="black">
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"], 'p/file.jpg');

?>
```

`$_FILES["file"]` = The file you get from the page;

`p/file.jpg`= The path of where you upload the photo

To upload to more folders just copy paste the code like so:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"], 'firstFolder/file.jpg');
copy('firstFolder/file.jpg', 'secondFolder/file.jpg');
copy('firstFolder/file.jpg', 'thirdFolder/file.jpg');
```

Comment: how could i do this to more folders? I mean i need  to do this for 3 folders

Comment: @CapitaoJarda edited the answer so you can see how to do it

Comment: sorry man i don't know were i should add that code, but i mean what i want is when i insert products u have 3 cat_type that are Drones, computers, laptops, this 3 categories have 3 diferent folders where is the photos for each category and i don't think dat example will work :(

Comment: Can you call `move_uploaded_file()` three times like that? I thought being called `move_xx()` meant that it would _move_ the file, so on the second and third calls you'll get a "file not found" error, surely?

Comment: Just because the OP needs to display the image in three categories surely doesn't mean that the image file itself needs to be stored three times, does it? Surely a better design would be to store the image against the product, and have that references from as many categories as needed?

Comment: @droopsnoot I am giving a solution to what he asked for.. not to what I think it's better.
If you have an answer to post or a suggestion you should comment the main question and not my answer and post along with it your solution. :)

Comment: OK, fair enough - I think the question has been answered sufficiently. But I think your second and third `move_uploaded_file()` calls will fail, won't they?

Comment: @droopsnoot Well... considering that I'm trying to move a file that has already been moved they might fail.
In my opinion even storing images is wrong.
Just convert them to base64 and store in db with an attribute that will differenciate them between drone, computer and laptops.

Comment: @Synapsis How is storing a file physically wrong? Your comment makes no sense at all

Comment: @DarkBee storing an image instead of a base64 string takes more space and needs more time to be loaded.
A simple string won't take as much time and bandwidth to load compared to an image.
No need to be rude btw :)

Comment: Storing an image in base64 will increase the size of the image by an average of 33% and they can't be cached by the browser. In these times it's not uncommon to use `CDN`'s to deliver images making the page load faster. That's why I said that it makes no sense, not being rude.

Comment: @DarkBee and Synapsis request i did still doesn't work :( could you guys help me? thank you

Comment: @CapitaoJarda Hey, if you really need help contact me on telegram (if you don t have it download it) you can write to me at "@AScotto133".
I will help you out :)

Comment: I have also edited the answer to make the code actually work

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");

$code = ($_POST['product_code']);
$name = ($_POST['product_name']);
$cat = ($_POST['category']);
$cat_type = ($_POST['cat_type']);
$fees = ($_POST['price']);
$quant = ($_POST['product_qty']);
$photo = ($_POST['product_img_name']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO products(product_code,product_name,category,cat_type,price,product_qty,product_img_name) VALUES ('$code','$name','$cat','$cat_type','$fees','$quant', '$photo')";

if (mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)){

    $dir = false;
    if($cat_type == 'Drones'){
        $dir = 'res/got/';
    }
    else if($cat_type == 'Computers'){
        $dir = 'res/hp/';
    }
    else if($cat_type == 'Laptops'){
        $dir = 'res/hg/';
    }

    if($dir){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"], $dir.time().'_file.jpg');
    }

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("New product added. Add more!");</script>';
    header("Location:http://localhost/Fly With US/add_product.php");
} 
else{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error Occured");</script>';
    header("Location:http://localhost/Fly With US/add_product.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: didn't work  :( the path is this C:\xampp\htdocs\Fly With US\res\got

Comment: i think you just need to use res/got/ or do u need to put entire path?

Comment: Don't i need to use more code for when u click submit? or something?

Comment: Your project directory is `Fly With US`, first of all, try to change the directory name as `flyWithUS` (remove space), and your file `add.php` and target directory `res` should be inside `flyWithUS`, also as @DarkBee suggested, add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `form` tag, and then try,

Comment: yea res is inside of the folder and the folder have spaces so Fly With US

Comment: i should add enctype="multipart/form-data in the add_product.php?

Comment: No need to add in `add.php`, just add in form tag at `add_product.php` like this: `<form name="productForm" method="post" action="add.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >`

Comment: didn't work, do you wanna do teamviwer for check? if u are available i can show you

Comment: any more ideas?

Comment: If still not working, then you need to learn about the basic first,